# how to optimize the query here with select_related?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, django-select-related

i have

```py
class A(models.Model):
    field_a = models.OneToOneField(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class B(models.Model):
    field_b = models.charField()
```

how to write the most optimum query here using select_related or something else?
In my use case i need to use both, `field_a` of model A and `field_b` of model B somewhere in my code. So can i fetch both the objects in one db hit?

```py
queryset_b = B.objects.get(field_b="some name")
queryset_a = A.objects.get(b=queryset_b).field_a
field_a_of_model = queryset_a
field_b_of_model = queryset_b.field_b
# then some manipulation with both fields
```

it hits the db twice. Can i do this thing in one db hit using select_related so that it fetches both object at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [lookup that span relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

```
a = A.objects.get(b__field_b="some name")
```

This would result in single query to database

---

If you want single query to access fields from b too use [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

```
a = A.objects.select_related().get(b__field_b="some name")
a.field_a.field_b
```

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. I also want to access fields of model B. I have updated the question.

Comment: what if in `model B` i have another `foreignkey field` `field_c` so...how can i fetch that object also in this query? because now if i do `a.field_a.field_c` will again make a db query.

Comment: what do you mean by fetch

Comment: by fetch i mean that only one query can get the object of field_c also in cache. like i said..`a.field_a.field_c` should not make another db query

Comment: select_related('field_b__field_c')

Comment: you have following in documentation i have attached regarding select_related